# How to bind title in MVC using knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to display a title on the image. When I am on the signing page, the data-bind title working fine and I can see the title displaying over the image. However, as soon as I sign in, the data-bind title stops working.

```html
 
_layout.cshtml

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container" style="width:100%">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="height:50px">
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand" 
                   style="margin-left:2px;margin-top:12px;padding:0px;margin-top:7px">
                    <img style="margin-top:4px;height:32px;" data-bind="attr: {title: versionNumber()}" src="~/images/Scheduler-transparent.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")

        </div>
    </nav>
```

JS file that gets value I want to display on the logo

```html
// versionNumber.js

var versionNumber = ko.observable('');

var url = window.location.origin + '/account/GetVersionNumber';

CallService("Get", url)
    .done(function (data) {
        versionNumber(data);
        console.log("Version number", versionNumber());
    });
```

The title on signing page is being added on img element
[image]

But not after I sign in
[image]

Comment: I am not familar with asp.net and you should try to give us a running example somewhere. As the title-attribut on 2nd screenshot is totally missing, I assume that the whole HTML (at least this part) was not binded to knockout. Maybe overwritten by asp.net somewhere?